# Javascript replace byte array sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, find

I'm trying to replace a bit of text in a binary file. I turn the binary file into a byte array in js and then try to use the sequence of bytes I want to change. However, it seems the byte array is not a string, so I can't replace the sequence. I've tried toString(), which just gives me loads of escaping (e.g. 65/,34/,102/, etc) I've also tried join() function, but that seems to put spaces in the byte array, which doesnt preserve the array (it seems to change it, by adding spaces, which makes a big difference when I later encode using base64).

I'm guessing I could just loop over the array and change the bytes individually, but how would I be able to just do that within a specified sequence? Is it possible to do a find and replace on an array?

```
function read(){
    var binaryfile = readbytes('C:/binaryfile.txt');
    var replaced = binaryfile.join(" ");
    //replaced = binaryfile.toString();
    var Header1 = "67 99 110 75 0 0 0 0 70 66 67 ";
    var Header2 = "67 99 110 75 0 0 0 0 80 70 67 45 0";
    finalstring = replaced.replace(Header1, Header2);   
    alert(replaced);
}


function readbytes(s){
    var f = new File(s);
    var i,a,c;
    var d = [];
    if (f.isopen) {
        c = f.eof;
        for(i=0;i<c ;i++){ 
            a = f.readbytes(1); 
            d.push(a);
        }   
        return d;
        f.close();
    } else {
        post("could not open file: " + s + "n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the byte sequence (i.e. Header1) that you are searching in an array as bytes. In your binaryfile create slices by using `Array.prototype.slice(index, index + searcharray.length)` of same length with your search array. Starting comparing both by `Array.prototype.every()` from index 0 to binarfile.length-searcharray.length by 1 increments of index.

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling that size might be the way forward. However, my actual header string that im trying to replace, is a different size (sorry I should have made this clear in my example), so I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. I made a similar algorithm a while back, dug it up and modified it for you. <strike>It will work as long as dataFrom and dataTo are the same length (as long as the fileData size doesn't change).</strike> It will work regardless of size differences.

```js
var replaceBytes = function(fileData, dataFrom, dataTo) {
    var loc = 0, sz = fileData.length;
    var checksComplete = 0, totalChecks = dataFrom.length;
    while(loc < sz && checksComplete < totalChecks) {
        if(dataFrom[checksComplete] === fileData[loc++])
            checksComplete++;
        else checksComplete = 0;
        }
    if(checksComplete === totalChecks) {
        // Match found -- creates a new (regular) array to return
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(
            fileData = Array.prototype.slice.call(fileData),
            [loc - totalChecks, totalChecks].concat(dataTo)
            );
        }
    return fileData;
    };

document.body.innerText = '[' + replaceBytes(
    new Uint8Array([0,0,0,0,67,99,110,75,0,0,0,0,70,66,67,0,0,0,0]), // File data
    [67,99,110,75,0,0,0,0,70,66,67], // Byte sequence to search for
    [67,99,110,75,0,0,0,0,80,70,67,20,40,60,80] // Byte sequence to replace with
    ).join(',') + ']';
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'm afraid I omitted that the strings are different that Im trying to replace, Ive updated my question with the correct strings. Im sure this will come in useful though.

Comment: @Ke. I've modified my answer so hopefully it now suits your needs.